# Compiler or Standard C++ Library - new and delete

Tags: c++, kernel

I am developing C++ coding for software (kernel) without any library. I am confused about the new operator and delete operator. I have implemented KMalloc() and KFree(). Now, I want to know if the following coding will work without any Standard C++ Library.

```
void *mem = KMalloc(sizeof(__type__));
Object *obj = new (mem) ();
```

If this will not work, then how will I setup the vtables or whatever object structure there is in a preallocated space without any Std Lib.

Comment: It's called placement new, and is an intrinsic language feature.

Comment: What kernel are you thinking of? Your own, or the Linux kernel.

Comment: It will work. But you can also just overload the global operators `new` and `delete` and make your life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what other answers have already said, you might want to overload `operator new` and `operator delete` in order for you not needing to do the `KMalloc()` plus placement `new` trick all the time.

```
// In the global namespace.

void* operator new
(
    size_t size
)
{
    /* You might also check for `KMalloc()`'s return value and throw
     * an exception like the standard `operator new`. This, however,
     * requires kernel-mode exception support, which is not that easy
     * to get up and running.
     */
    return KMalloc( size );
}


void* operator new[]
(
    size_t size
)
{
    return KMalloc( size );
}


void operator delete
(
    void* what
)
{
    KFree( what );
}


void operator delete[]
(
    void* what
)
{
    KFree( what );
}
```

Then, code like the following will work by calling your `KMalloc()` and `KFree()` routines when necessary, along with all necessary constructors like placement `new` would do.

```
template<typename Type>
class dumb_smart_pointer
{
    public:
        dumb_smart_pointer()
        : pointer( nullptr )
        {}


        explicit dumb_smart_pointer
        (
            Type* pointer
        )
        : pointer( pointer )
        {}


        ~dumb_smart_pointer()
        {
            if( this->pointer != nullptr )
            {
                delete this->pointer;
            }
        }


        Type& operator*()
        {
            return *this->pointer;
        }


        Type* operator->()
        {
            return this->pointer;
        }


    private:
        Type* pointer;
};


dumb_smart_pointer<int> my_pointer = new int( 123 );
*my_pointer += 42;
KConsoleOutput << *my_pointer << '\n';
```

Answer (score 3):

You first should define what C++ standard are you targeting. I guess it is at least C++11.

Then, if you code in C++ for some operating system kernel, beware and study carefully the relevant [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specifications (the details depend even of the version of your C++ compiler, and gory details like even exception handling and stack unwinding matter a lot).

Notice that the Linux kernel ABI is not C++ friendly (it is not the same as Linux user-land ABI for x86-64). So coding in C++ for the Linux kernel is not reasonable.

You probably want

```
 void *mem = KMalloc(sizeof(Object));
 Object *obj = new (mem) Object();
```

The second statement uses the [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) feature of C++, which will run the constructor on the (more or less "unitialized") memory zone passed as placement.

<sup>(notice that bitwise copy of C++ objects -e.g. with `memcpy`- is undefined behavior in general (except for [POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure)s); you need to use constructors and assignment operators)</sup>

There is no "placement delete", but you can *explicitly* run the destructor: `obj->~Object()` after which any use of the object pointed by the `obj` pointer is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

> Now, I want to know if that code will work without any Standard C++ Library.

It might be much harder than what you believe. You need to understand all the details of the ABI targeted by your compiler, and that is hard.

Notice that running *properly* [constructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29) (and [destructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_%28computer_programming%29)) -in a good enough order- is of paramount importance for C++; practically speaking, they are notably initializing the (implicit) [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) field[s], without which your object can crash (as soon as any `virtual` member function or destructor gets called).

Read also about the [rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) (for C++11).

Coding your own kernel in C++ practically requires understanding a lot of details about your C++ implementation (and ABI).

NB: practically speaking, bitwise copy with `memcpy`  of smart pointers, of `std::stream`-s, of `std::mutex`-es, of `std::thread`-s - and perhaps even of standard containers and of `std::string`-s etc...-  is very likely to make a disaster. If you dare doing such bad things, you really need to look into the details of your particular implementations...

Comment: I am coding my own kernel.

Comment: Then you should invest weeks of efforts to understand all the gory details of your C++ compiler's ABI.

Comment: AFAIK, there are (not very sane) ways to get C++ code running under the Linux kernel. However, this means you would have to deal with lots of obscure GCC options, linker script magic, random kernel oopses/panics on the first tries, and RTTI/exception support is a no-no. Don't even get me started on global constructors/destructors.